# I don't know what is going on in this code (Sub setting lists)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I just need to know what is going on with this code:

> To subset both regular Python lists and numpy arrays, you can use square brackets:
>
> ```
> x = [4 , 9 , 6, 3, 1]
> x[1]
> ```

What does `x[1]` do exactly? Does it track the index of 1 on the list above?

> ```
> import numpy as np
> y = np.array(x)
> y[1]
> ```

What does `y[1]` do exactly? Does it track the index of 1 on the list above?

> For numpy specifically, you can also use boolean numpy arrays:
>
> ```
> x = [4 , 9 , 6, 3, 1]
> x[1]
> import numpy as np
> y = np.array(x)  
> y[1]
> ```

Does `y = np.array(x)` convert list x to a numpy array?

I don't know what `y[1]` does. Does it index 1?

([Image of the original problem for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A8jG.png))

Answer (score 0):

The first instruction:

```
x = [4, 9, 6, 3, 1]
```

creates an ordinary, pythonic **list**.

Elements of this list have indices - consecutive integers starting from *0*,
so `x[1]` retrieves *9* (the second element of this list).

Then `y = np.array(x)` creates a *numpy* **array**, filled with values
taken from *x*.

Elements of this array have also indices, also startig from *0*.

So `y[1]` retrieves also *9*.

You asked whether this is a **conversion**.

It is actually **not** any conversion, as *x* is still a **list** and
*y* is a **separate** entity (an **array**), both with their own
data buffers.

You can confirm it by saving any other value in a chosen element of *x*
and then check that the respective element of *y* has the "old" value.

Then `high = y < 5` creates a **boolean** array, with each element
stating whether the corresponding element of *y* is less than 5.

And the last statement `y[high]` is an example of **boolean indexing**.
It retrieves elements of *y* with values less than *5*.